# Calling a python API from another program

Tags: python, json

I have an Python API that I'm trying to call and print the city name for a given ip range. The python API looks as below:

```
import datetime as dt

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request



class IpRangeSearch:

    RANGES = {
        'Tokyo': [
            {'start': '10.10.0.0', 'end': '10.10.255.255'},
            {'start': '192.168.1.0', 'end': '192.168.1.255'},
        ],
        'Paris': [
            {'start': '10.12.0.0', 'end': '10.12.255.255'},
            {'start': '172.16.10.0', 'end': '172.16.11.255'},
            {'start': '192.168.2.0', 'end': '192.168.2.255'},
        ]
    }

    def __init__(self):
       pass

    def get_city(self, ip):
        for city, ipranges in self.RANGES.items():
            for iprange in ipranges:
                if ip >= iprange['start'] and ip <= iprange['end']:
                    return city


app = Flask(__name__)
ip_range_search = IpRangeSearch()



@app.route('/ip_city/<ip>')
def ip_city(ip):

    return jsonify({'city': ip_range_search.get_city(ip)})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I'm calling the API from another python program:

```
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import requests

response = requests.get("http://0.0.0.0:5000/ip_city/10.12.1.1")

print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```

Ideally the above code should print:

```
200
{
  "city": Paris
}
```

But its printing:

```
200
{
  "city": null
}
```

I'm not sure why, but when I try to run the API code to parse the json structure as a standalone function - the code prints the output in the correct format.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think `get_city()` wants to _return_ city, not _print_ it.

Comment: You have not handled the case where it doesnt find an entry. You need a value to return in that case. If you were expecting a value to be found in your case you need to debug your function.

Comment: I ran this code in a shell and it did return `'Paris'`, so the basic code appears to be fine.  Perhaps there's some problem with the web scaffolding?  Try adding the ip to the returned jsonify dict, so you can see it displayed and make sure it's being received correctly.

Comment: Just in case these IP addresses are merely examples and your actual data is different, do be aware that strings can compare differently than actual numbers -- .i.e. `'2.2.2.2'` is _greater than_ `'10.10.10.10'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ip_city` function return the `json` object, just call the `json` function on the `requests` object

```
response = requests.get("http://0.0.0.0:5000/ip_city/10.12.1.1").json()
```

**UPD:**

And maybe `IP` didn't found in the your function, and your function return `None`

Just add `else` statement, and check it.

```
def get_city(ip):
    for city, ipranges in RANGES.items():
        for iprange in ipranges:
            if ip >= iprange['start'] and ip <= iprange['end']:
                return city
    return 'IP not found'
```